# background-color not applying to HTML element?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS and this forum.

Could someone explain why the following code doesn't make the background-color behind the text green?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>this is my title</title>
    
    <style>
      .container {
        background-color: green;
      }

      p {
        font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: blue;
      }

    </style>
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class=”container”>
        <p>Cardigan aesthetic direct trade, migas locavore shoreditch DIY bicycle rights lyft street art bitters.</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

If I add this as an inline style to the div it works??

(Also, I tried creating a separate style sheet first, and then tried adding the style to the head because that didn't work.  The

selector styles do work).

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use "smart quotes" for attributes in HTML, you must use either `"` or `'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its `"container"`. You have used wrong quotes for your `container` in this way `”container”`. You should use `"container"` in double quotes or in single quotes `'container'`

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
}

p {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>this is my title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Cardigan aesthetic direct trade, migas locavore shoreditch DIY bicycle rights lyft street art bitters.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you muchly, was going mad with this - I copied this code off an online example. cheers.

Comment: I understand that.Keep practicing, Rather than copying implement the code by your own. You can go through https://www.w3schools.com/ and can learn more. Please accept my answer if you feel it helpful. There will be a tick mark on left hand side of the answer. If you click on it, It will turn into green. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

`<div class=”container”>` uses invalid quotation marks!

Replace it with `<div class="container">`

Comment: You've added nothing more than Sai has in their answer

Comment: @freefaller Ohh, I was already preparing my answer when he must've posted. How does being a minute slow make me eligible for a downvote?